# Bootstrap Form Control - Django Form HTML

Tags: html, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been having trouble adding HTML for Form Control to my Django form. I know (from other features) that I have Bootstrap properly integrated into the project. No fields are showing when I try to integrate form control into the page.

The form has two fields: 1) a file field, and 2) a boolean field. Below is my HTML (I don't include the submit button after/closing tags.

```
<form id='name' action = "" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <!-- {{ form }} --> #Note that when this is not commented out and when the lines below are commented out, the form works correctly, but obviously with no form control.



      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {% if field.auto_id == "file" %}
                <div class="form-group{% if field.errors%} has-error{% endif %}">
                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-xs-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <label for="file">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="file" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Test</small>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                      {{field}}
                    </div>
                    {{ field.errors }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              {% else %}

              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the problem now? no field is showing?

Comment: Correct, no fields are showing. Updated description.

Comment: yes because you are using a wrong name, do post your modelform or the form you want to render

Comment: What do you mean? What wrong name am I using?

Comment: if field.auto_id change it to field.label == "file"

Comment: For debugging: output the field labels in the `else` clause and you'll see whether it ever goes into your `if` block.

Comment: ^^field.name helped (not field.label). Thanks for directing me to that line!